# Unknown custom element in Vuetify

Tags: laravel, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am new to Vuetify and vue. I am using vue and vuetify but due some reason I am not able open my page.The error I am getting when I run my project:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at resources/js/components/appContainer.vue

My code:

```
appContainer.vue

<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      app
    >
      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item link>
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>mdi-home</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>Home</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
        <v-list-item link>
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>mdi-contact-mail</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>Contact</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-app-bar
      app
      color="indigo"
      dark
    >
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Application</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-content>
      <v-container
        class="fill-height"
        fluid
      >
        <v-row
          align="center"
          justify="center"
        >
          <v-col class="text-center">
            <v-tooltip left>
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn
                  :href="source"
                  icon
                  large
                  target="_blank"
                  v-on="on"
                >
                  <v-icon large>mdi-code-tags</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </template>
              <span>Source</span>
            </v-tooltip>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-footer
      color="indigo"
      app
    >
      <span class="white--text">&copy; 2019</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      source: String,
    },
    data: () => ({
      drawer: null,
    }),
  }
</script>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue'

import Vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify);

Vue.component('app-container', require('./components/appContainer.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    Vuetify,
    Vue,
    el: '#app',
});
```

spa.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <app-container></app-container>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't given an export name for your app-container element. Try the below.

appContainer.vue

```
<template>
  ...
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app-container'
    props: {
      source: String,
    },
    data: () => ({
      drawer: null,
    }),
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the drawer from null to false:

```
data: () => ({
    drawer: false,
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make your component name camelcase.
Like Vue.component('appContainer',require('./components/apContainer.vue').default);